# CDF that combines properties of Pareto and Exponential

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, pareto-distribution

Let $Y$ be a random variable defined on the domain $[1;\infty)$ that is distributed according to the cdf $G_Y(y)$.

A Pareto distribution,
$$ G_Y(y) = 1 - y^{-\theta}$$
has the property that
$$ P(Y>ay) = 1 - G_Y(ay) = a^{-\theta} (1-G_Y(y)).$$
Similarly, the exponential distribution,
$$ G_Y(y) = 1 - \exp(-\theta (y-1)).$$
has the property that
$$ P(Y>y+b) = 1- G_Y(y+b) = \exp(b)^{-\theta} (1-G_Y(y)).$$

Is there any distribution that combines these two properties, i.e. where
$$ P(Y>ay+b) = z(a,b) (1-G_Y(y)),$$ 
where $z(a,b)$ is some function of $a$ and $b$?

I expect this distribution to work for any real parameters $a$ or $b$ where $a$ is strictly positive and $b$ can be zero or negative. I expect $z(a,b)$ to be a function of both $a$ and $b$.

The solution should hold for all possible values of Y that are in the domain $[1;\infty)$, and any combination of $a$ and $b$ where $a$ is strictly positive. Of course, if a solution can only found for a subset of these, then that's better than nothing. One might has to restrict $a$ and $b$ such that $aY+b$ has the same domain as $Y$.

Comment: This varying, ambiguous notation is confusing: how are "$G(y)$" and "$G(y\gt aY)$" related?  What kinds of mathematical objects do "$y$" and "$Y$" represent?  What are the possible values of $a$ and $b$?  What are the implicit quantifiers in your statements?  What properties of the function $z$ do you require?  (After all, $z$ doesn't have to change when either of $a$ or $b$ change.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, whuber. I have edited the question. Please let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: What you call a "Fréchet distribution" can be rewritten $G_Y(y)=1-\exp(-\theta y).$ Thus, depending on what you conceive as being its domain, this is an *exponential* distribution either for $y$ or $-y.$ Is there perhaps a typographical error somewhere? Also, the properties you quote are ill-defined: what are the implicit quantifiers on $y,$ $a,$ and $b$?

Comment: Thanks, whuber. I have changed the name to the exponential distribution and clarified the domain for the random variable $Y$. I am not sure what you mean by 'implicit quantifiers'.

Comment: Do these conditions need to hold for *all* $a$ and $b$ and $y$ or just for *some* of them?  "All" and "some" are the kinds of quantifiers you need to supply to clarify your question.

Comment: Ok. It should hold for all possible values of $Y$ that are in the domain $[1;\infty)$, and any combination of $a$ and $b$ where $a$ is strictly positive. Of course, if a solution can only found for a subset of these, then that's better than nothing.

Comment: Please edit the question rather than replying through comments.

Comment: Why can't you have $b>0$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment, dlnB. $b$ can be positive.

Comment: This is really a great question. I spent a long time trying to derive a contradiction here. Any progress?

Comment: Your property could usefully be rephrased using conditional proabilities. See [my answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/332524/10479) for an interesting property of the Generalized Pareto Distibution and its relation to a functional equation.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible distribution on $[1,\infty)$ satisfying the key equation above of
\begin{align}
P[&Y>ay+b]=z(a,b)\,P[Y>y]\\
&\text{ whenever } a>0, b\le 0, y\ge 1
\end{align}
is the distribution with $P[Y=1]=1$, concentrated entirely at $y=1$.

If the distribution is not concentrated entirely at $Y=1$, then:

- Let $s$ be such that $s>1$ and $P[Y>s]$ is positive.
- Let $t$ be such that $t>s$ and $P[Y>t]<P[Y>s]$.
- Let $r = \sqrt{s}$, so $1<r<s<t$, and $P[Y>r]$ is also positive.
- Solve for $a$ and $b$ such that

\begin{align}
ar+b&=r\\
as+b&=t\\
\end{align}
Subtracting these two equations gives $a(s-r)=(t-r)$, so $a>1$, and that combined with the first of them gives $b<0$. Now:

The key equation for $y=r$ gives $P[Y>r]=z(a,b)P[Y>r]$, so $z(a,b)=1$.

The key equation for $y=s$ gives $P[Y>t]=z(a,b)P[Y>s]$, so $z(a,b)<1$.

This is a contradiction, so the distribution must have been entirely concentrated at $Y=1$.